# sending customParams in Twilio SMS node js

Tags: node.js, twilio, sms, twilio-node

I am sending SMS to users using Twilio SMS service, in nodejs. I am using [twilio npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio).

I want to send customParams while sending the sms and get those params in webhook response when it gets delivere, so that I can update my database.

For example, something like this:

```
customParams: {
   userId: <userid>
}
```

Here is my code to create the sms:

```
twilioClient.messages.create({
    to: USER_PHONE,
    body: smsBody,
    messagingServiceSid: MSG_SERVICE_ID,
}).then(resp => {
    console.log('SMS sent', resp)
})
```

Please let me know how can we possibly send sms with custom parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a webhook to let you know when the message is delivered you will need to set a `statusCallback` URL. You can add information to that URL by assigning query string parameters.

For example:

```js
const statusCallbackUrl = new URL("https://example.com/statusCallback");
statusCallbackUrl.searchParams.append("userId", userId);

twilioClient.messages.create({
    to: USER_PHONE,
    body: smsBody,
    messagingServiceSid: MSG_SERVICE_ID,
    statusCallback: statusCallbackUrl.toString()
}).then(resp => {
    console.log('SMS sent', resp)
})
```

When the webhook request is made to your status callback URL the query parameters will be sent to and you will be able to use the `userId` to find your user.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this worked for me. I have one more query, I have created a messaging service, and for incoming sms, can the same **statusCallback** be used ?

Comment: For a Messaging Service, by default it uses the statusCallback configured for the Messaging Service. I believe you can tell the Messaging Service to use the Webhook URL associated with each individual number in the messaging service, which is a new feature. Go under where you configured you messaging service and you should see the action to take with incoming messages.